# Fundamental theorem of calculus for analytic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to solve the following problem but I have no idea where to start. Any hint or suggestions could be really helpful, thanks!

Suppose the continuous functions $f(e^{i \theta})$ on the unit circle satisfies $|f(e^{i \theta})|\leq M$ and $|\int_{|z|=1}f(z) dz| = 2 \pi M$. Show that $f(z) = c*\bar{z}$ for some constant $c$ with modulus $|c|=M$.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change variable $z = e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, then $|\int ... | \leq \int |...| \leq 2 \pi M$. The equality occurs when?
2. Observe that $f(z) = c \bar z \Leftrightarrow zf(z) = c$, as $|z| = 1$.